# Set header in HTTP getUrl

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am trying to fetch data from http getUrl function but unable to set the header in request.

**var response = http.getUrl(url,{format:'json'});**

In response I am getting data in 
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8

I need to set header **content-type:"application/json"** to get in correct format but there is no way to set header in get call.

Please help me to resolve this small issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
I resolved the issue, we can add headers in options object and pass as an argument 
in getUrl function

var options = { 
    format: 'json',
    query: {
      term: type
    },
   headers:{'Accept':'application/json'}
  };
 var response = http.getUrl(config.get('remote.url') + '/search', options);
```